# How do I Marshal a struct with an embdedded struct field to be a flat JSON object in Go?

Tags: json, go, struct, encoding

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type City struct {
    City string `json:"City"`
    Size int        `json:"Size"`
}

type Location struct {
    City City
    State string `json:"State"`
}

func main() {
    city := City{City: "San Francisco", Size: 8700000}
    loc := Location{}
    loc.State = "California"
    loc.City = city
    js, _ := json.Marshal(loc)
    fmt.Printf("%s", js)
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
{"City":{"City":"San Francisco","Size":8700000},"State":"California"}
```

The intended output I want is:

```
{"City":"San Francisco","Size":8700000,"State":"California"}
```

I've read this [blog post](http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/) for custom JSON Marshalling, but I can't seem to get it to work for a struct with another embedded struct.

I tried flattening the struct by defining a custom `MarshalJSON` function but I still get the same nested output:

```
func (l *Location) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
            City string `json:"City"`
            Size int    `json:"Size"`
            State string `json:"State"`
    }{
        City: l.City.City,
        Size: l.City.Size,
        State:   l.State,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anonymous field to flatten the JSON output:

```
type City struct {
    City string `json:"City"`
    Size int        `json:"Size"`
}

type Location struct {
    City     // <-- anonymous field has type, but no field name
    State string `json:"State"`
}
```

The `MarshalJSON` method is ignored in the question because code encodes a `Location` value, but the `MarshalJSON` method is declared with a pointer receiver.  Fix by encoding a `*Location`.

```
js, _ := json.Marshal(&loc)  // <-- note &
```

Comment: that does seem to work! Is there a way around needing to define every nested field and bringing it up a level? e.g. City and Size just need to be brought up a level, but if the City struct had many fields, it would be very verbose. Additionally, why does making the field anonymous work?

Comment: @ajoseps An anonymous field works because the encoding/json package is written to flatten anonymous fields.  The other approach is to flatten with a `MarshalJSON` method as in the question. See updated answer on how to make that work.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I was confused since I'm using `graphql-go` which I assumed used the default `encoding/json` for its output, but it does not seem to. When I change the field to be anonymous, it does not flatten it.

Comment: seems like I'm not the only one with the same issue: https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/issues/170