# Use an inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, go

I am doing a practice with SQL Server and Go, and now I am making a query on a table which has an inner join against two tables, the main table is user and the tables to which it is performing the inner join are user state and user roles, but at the moment of being able to show a list of all the users, it shows me an object from the other two tables which I am doing the inner join.

This is my structure:

```
type User struct {
    Id_User       int64     `json:"id_user,omitempty"`
    Name          string    `json:"name,omitempty"`
    NameSecond    string    `json:"name_second,omitempty"`
    Surname       string    `json:"surname,omitempty"`
    SurnameSecond string    `json:"surname_second,omitempty"`
    Email         string    `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Password      string    `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Id_RoleUser   UserRole  `json:"id_roleUser,omitempty"`
    Id_UserState  UserState `json:"id_userState,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time `json:"crated_at,omitempty"`
}
```

I know that it is showing me the UserRole and UserState structures as an object, because then I specify them but there is no way to be able to show only the name as if it were another field of the structure?

This my code:

```
func ListUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var user model.User

    db := storage.Connection()
    tsql := `
    SELECT
        Id_User,
        U.Name + ' ' + NameSecond,
        Surname + ' ' + SurnameSecond,
        Email,
        UR.Name,
        US.Name
    FROM
        Users U
            INNER JOIN UserRoles UR ON UR.Id_RoleUser = U.Id_RoleUser
            INNER JOIN UserStates US ON US.Id_UserState = U.Id_UserState
    `

    rows, err := db.QueryContext(context.Background(), tsql)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    users := []model.User{}

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&user.Id_User, &user.Name, &user.Surname, &user.Email, &user.Id_RoleUser.Name, &user.Id_UserState.Name); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        users = append(users, user)
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(users)
}
```

This my JSON generated:

```
{
  "id_user": 5,
  "name": "Joan Sebastian",
  "surname": "Tovar Osorio",
  "email": "jsto@hotmail.com",
  "id_roleUser": {
    "name": "Desarrollador",
    "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "id_userState": {
    "name": "Inactivo",
    "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "crated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106352/11810946) help? (there are other options but using an anonymous field is probably the simplest). This assumes that your aim is to flatten the JSON output.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you rewrite your heading as a question? It helps people to easily zero in on questions they can help with. Thank you!

Comment: @Brits thank you it was a great help, i had no knowledge about that

Comment: @tdelozie understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: You can implement the ***json.Marshaler*** interface and define the MarshalJson function for another struct which has your required fields.

```
type MyUser struct {
    Id_User       int64     `json:"id_user,omitempty"`
    Name          string    `json:"name,omitempty"`
    NameSecond    string    `json:"name_second,omitempty"`
    Surname       string    `json:"surname,omitempty"`
    SurnameSecond string    `json:"surname_second,omitempty"`
    Email         string    `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Password      string    `json:"password,omitempty"`
    RoleUserName  string  `json:"roleUser_name,omitempty"`
    UserStateName  string `json:"userState_name,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time `json:"crated_at,omitempty"`
}

func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    mu := MyUser{
        Id_User:       u.Id_User,
        Name:          u.Name,
        NameSecond:    u.NameSecond,
        Surname:       u.Surname,
        SurnameSecond: u.SurnameSecond,
        Email:         u.Email,
        Password:      u.Password,
        RoleUserName:  u.Id_RoleUser.Name,
        UserStateName: u.Id_UserState.Name,
        CreatedAt:     u.CreatedAt,
        UpdatedAt:     u.UpdatedAt,
    }
    return json.Marshal(mu)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but that structure does not work very well for the rest of the application when it generates the inner joins on other tables